# Python : how to pass a class object in subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, popen

code :
B.py - `B` (executable)

```
Get the object here and call it's functions
```

A.py - `A` (executable)

```
from subprocess import Popen

class x():

    def __init__():
        pass
    def A1():
        ------
    def A2():
        ------
    <---------->

    def AN():
       -------

object_x = x()
Popen(['B','-class_args', 'x'])
```

I have two python executables. I have a class defined in the first executable. I have created an object from that. I want to pass that object to the second executable using `Popen`. As in `Popen` I can only pass strings, Is it possible to pass an object??

Comment: If you're writing this code (and something someone else had already written wouldn't depend on passing Python objects on the command line), why don't you just use B as a Python library, rather than an external executable?

Comment: I can't use it as library. It's an executable already defined.

Comment: If it's already defined, doesn't that mean you can't modify it to accept an object on the command line (if there were a way to do so)? And do note that the *conventional* way to create a Python executable is as a library with a defined entry point, so you can either run it as an executable *or* import it as a library. See http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation

Comment: It can be modified. I agree that I can use it as a library but I want to use it as an executable.

Comment: If you have a compelling reason for that intent, it might be worth discussing it -- you could be in a use case where the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module (which handles all the (de)serialization, and the work of starting and monitoring your child processes, for you) is the right tool for the job.

Comment: Thank you. I will give a try to that.

Answer (score 4):

The UNIX command line is, at its core, a list of C strings (which is to say, strings terminated at the first NUL value following their starting position in memory).

You cannot pass things that cannot be converted to NUL-delimited strings.

This means you could potentially `pickle` a Python object and `base64`-encode the result (base64-encoding overhead could be avoided if you passed the serialized object on stdin, such that NULs were allowed), and pass *that*, base64-decoding and unpickling it later -- but on the command line, it *must* be a string with no NUL characters.

Comment: Is there a way other than pickle/unpickle??

Comment: `pickle` is not the only serialization/deserialization method in the world, but you'll *always* be doing serialization of some kind.